# Spring Cloud Configuration - Access shared properties file in all microservices

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, microservices

Inside my spring cloud config server application.properties. I have passed @EnableConfigServer in my application class

```
spring.application.name=CONFIG_SERVER
server.port=1080
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=PATH_TO_GITHUB_REPO
spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=USNM
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=PWD
spring.cloud.config.server.git.skip-ssl-validation=true
```

Inside my git repo application.properties

```
third-party-cred=MY_VALUE
```

In my spring cloud config client bootstrap.properties

```
server.port=1081
spring.application.name=MY_SERVICE
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:1080
```

I am trying to access property present in git repo using `@Value` inside my microservice but it is giving error `Could not resolve placeholder 'third-party-cred' in value "${third-party-cred}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

bootstrap.properties is not enable by default. Please add this dependency inside your microservice.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```